# Compute dim(Ker(T))?

Tags: linear-algebra

I have the following question regarding Kernel and Image:

[image]

Part b of the question asks to find $\dim(\ker(T))$. I am not sure how to go about this part, as I haven't dealt with finding kernel $T$ where the input and output vector space is $M_{n\times\ n} (\mathbb{R})$. I understand that the dimension of the vector space is $n^2$, but I could not figure out how to find $\ker(T)$ and its dimension. Could anyone help me with this problem?

Comment: The dimension of $M_{n\times n}(\Bbb R)$ is $n^2$, not $n^n$.

Comment: When in doubt, go back to basic definitions. What is the definition of the kernel of a linear map?

Answer (score 2):

Kernel of a linear transformation $L$ is the set of all vectors $v$ such that $L(v)=0$. In your case, that would mean all $A\in M_{n\times n}(\Bbb R)|A+A^T=0$. That is, $A=-A^T$. Thus you need to find the dimension of the space of $n\times n$ skew-symmetric matrices.

Note that in an $n\times n$ skew-symmetric matrix, the diagonal contains $0$ while the entries above (or below) the diagonal also control the corresponding entry below (or above) the diagonal. So you have the freedom of choosing independently the entries above (or below) the diagonal, which are $(n^2-n)/2$ in number, which is its dimension.

For better insight, this is a basis of the kernel for $n=3$:

$$\left\{\begin{bmatrix}0&1&0\\-1&0&0\\0&0&0\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}0&0&1\\0&0&0\\-1&0&0\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}0&0&0\\0&0&1\\0&-1&0\end{bmatrix}\right\}$$

Answer (score 0):

I guess that exercise 13 is about proving that every $n\times n$ matrix $A$ is uniquely the sum of a symmetric and an antisymmetric matrix, precisely
$$
A=\frac{1}{2}(A+A')+\frac{1}{2}(A-A')
$$
Since every symmetric matrix $A$ satisfies $T(A)=A$ and $T(A)$ is symmetric for every $A$, you see that the image of $T$ is the subspace consisting of all symmetric matrices.

The kernel of $T$ consists of all matrices $A$ such that $A+A'=0$, that is, the antisymmetric matrices.

Now you have two ways of determining $\dim\ker(T)$: either determine it directly or use the rank-nullity theorem after determining $\dim\operatorname{im}(T)$, because
$$
n^2=\dim\operatorname{im}(T)+\dim\ker(T)
$$
If you call $x_{ij}$ the entries of an antisymmetric matrix, the equations are
$$
x_{ji}=-x_{ij} \qquad 1\le i\le n,\quad 1\le j\le n
$$
This implies that $x_{ii}=0$ for $1\le i\le n$, so you have to count the number of unordered pairs $\{i,j\}$, with $i\ne j$. These are
$$
\binom{n}{2}=\frac{n(n-1)}{2}
$$
which thus is the dimension of $\dim\ker(T)$, because this gives the number of free variables for a matrix to belong to $\ker(T)$.